# I am using the Instantiate function to duplicate a prefab. When summoned it doesn't have a velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title suggests i'm struggling to get my prefab to move :(
For my prefab i have the Sprite Render component, the Boxcolider 2D copponent set to is Trigger, and the Rigidbody 2D component.
On an seperate object that is a child to my player I have a script that contains an array containing my prefab.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int damage;
   private float horizontal;
   public Transform player;
   public SpriteRenderer renderPlayer;
   public float speed = 60f;
   public GameObject[] attacks; 


    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            

          if(player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == true)
          {
            attacks[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = true;
            Instantiate(attacks[0], player.transform.position, attacks[0].transform.rotation);
            attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1f * speed, attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            

          }
          else if(player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == false)
          {
            
            attacks[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = false;
            Instantiate(attacks[0], player.transform.position, attacks[0].transform.rotation);
            attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-1f * speed, attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            

          }
        
        }

        
    }
}
```

This is my code for said script.
Almost everything so far has worked as intended.
When my Player is facing Right the projectile spawns facing Right.
vice versa for the left side.

however, upon spawning the projectile it doesnt move.
how would I go about fixing this.
To me the code seems fine even if it may be inefficent.

Thank you to whom ever can help!

I had attempted to change the order of opperations for my if statments.
structuring the if statement as such;

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            

          if(player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == true)
          {
            Instantiate(attacks[0], player.transform.position, attacks[0].transform.rotation);
            attacks[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = true;
            attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1f * speed, attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            

          }
          else if(player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == false)
          {
            Instantiate(attacks[0], player.transform.position, attacks[0].transform.rotation);
            attacks[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = false;
    attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-1f * speed, attacks[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            

          }
        
        }

        
    }
```

I presumed the problem derived from my Instantiate not being placed first within my if statements. However, when i tested this fix my flipY portion got delayed.
For example;
If i was facing Right it would spawn the first projectile facing left then the next projectiles would always be Right.
If to go and try to spawn it left from there it would then spawn one right then rest left. So on so forth.

This dillemma has costed me my last brain cell. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the instance being instantiated, e.g., `GameObject instance = Instantiate(...);`, and then modify that instance, e.g., `instance.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = ...`. You are currently trying to modify the velocity of the **prefab**, not the instantiated instance.

Comment: You can check which direction the player is facing using the player's SpriteRenderer's FlipX property. Instantiate a new projectile using Instantiate. Then set the projectile SpriteRenderer's FlipX property based on the player's facing direction.

Answer (score 0):

attacks is a prefab. You cannot assign values to prefab, you need to access the game object that was instantiated in your scene to move it.

The best way is to assign it to a game object while instantiating like below

```
my_spawned=Instantiate(prefab,transform.position,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

You can use the my_spawned game object to get the Rigidbody and assign velocity to it.

If you need more code sample, check out this article on [Unity Instantiate](https://vionixstudio.com/2019/11/27/unity-instantiate/).